# I am using QGIS 2.6.1 but I don't know how to split a state into two states

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a shapefile file of the states but my file is older one and after that one state in India converted into two different states so how can I separately show both the states on the map using QGIS. I also have the shapefiles files of districts within the states.

Comment: Hmm I may have misread the question as I'm unsure whether you want to display the old state **and** the two new states at the same time; or if you want to obtain the original attributes as described by @Redoute. Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/162143/edit) your question to clarify :)

Comment: I donot want to display old state but want to create new states from the old one.

Comment: You should [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/162143/edit) your question to include this new information. That way, your question could be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your districts outer borders match EXACTLY the border of the state, and the new state border is equal to district borders:

1. Make sure you have backups from the original shapefiles, in case something goes wrong.
2. Edit the state layer and delete the former state.
3. Change to the district layer, select and copy all districts of the two states.
4. Copy and paste the features from the district to the state layer.
5. Select all districts for one state and use "Merge Selected Features". In the following dialog you can get the new feature's attributes right. Do the same for the other state.

Comment: I tried as per your guidance. but I am facing problem in how to copy all districts and paste to state layer?